# How to implement tabs functionality like iOS in my Android app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

i am working on android app which contains five tabs. Every tabs need to multiple pages and on tab re select, it should go on First fragment of every tabs. Below is my code;

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.icon_discover));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.icon_my_cuddll));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.helpicon_feedback));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.icon_notifications));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.icon_user));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdaptor adapter = new PagerAdaptor
                (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                if(tab.getPosition()==4)
                {

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#87243D"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {



            }
        });
```

My pager adapter class is as follows:

```
public class PagerAdaptor extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;


    public PagerAdaptor(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                CuddllFragment tab1 = new CuddllFragment ();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                MyCuddllFragment tab2 = new MyCuddllFragment();
                return tab2;
            case 2:
//                CuddllConversationFragment tab3 = new CuddllConversationFragment();
                ConversationFragment conversationFragment = new ConversationFragment();
                return conversationFragment;

            case 3:
//                CuddllNotificationsFragment tab4 = new CuddllNotificationsFragment();
                Tab4ContainerFragment notificationPageFragment = new Tab4ContainerFragment();
                return notificationPageFragment;

            case 4:
                MyProfileFragment tab5 = new MyProfileFragment();
                return tab5;

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
```

Comment: If you have a specific question we would be happy to help you. But this question current is WAY too broad. It sounds like you want us to do your work for you. If you have a specific question please edit your question to rephrase and adding some code you have tried so far would be helpful. Read the help center for more information.

Comment: "Every tabs need to multiple pages" -- This sounds like a poor design. You shouldn't have pages within Tabs. The tabs are supposed to be the pages themselves

Comment: yes but app requirement is same. There are multiple page navigation in every tabs. for example, first fragment show list when click any list item then it will open details, then detail open the members page in same tab. and when again reselect the same tab then it should go in first page i.e list.

Answer (score 0):

**Tab.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TabFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/orange" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here **TabFragment.Java**

```
   package com.example.sachin.omcommunication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class TabFragment extends Fragment {

    public static TabLayout tabLayout;
    public static ViewPager viewPager;
    public static int int_items = 3 ;
    private int[] tabIcons = {
            R.drawable.tab_home,
            R.drawable.arrow,
            R.drawable.tab_home
    };
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View x =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home_page,null);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) x.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) x.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));


        tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
                //You tab icons
                int[] icons = {
                        R.drawable.tab_home,
                        R.drawable.arrow,
                        R.drawable.tab_home
                };

                for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(icons[i]);
                }
            }
        });
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


        return x;

    }
    class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        /**
         * Return fragment with respect to Position .
         */

        @Override
        public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
            switch (position){
                case 0 : return new HomePage();
                case 1 : return new Attendence();
                case 2 : return new Delivery();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return int_items;

        }

        /**
         * This method returns the title of the tab according to the position.
         */

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            switch (position){
                case 0 :
                    return "Primary";
                case 1 :
                    return "Social";
                case 2 :
                    return "Updates";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Try this.. might be work for you.

Comment: I have done same. my problem is how to replace fragment inside tabs, and when i re select the same tab it again should open first fragment.